# Interval width for truncated confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, binomial-distribution, simulation, proportion

I'm conducting a simulation study to compare different methods of constructing CIs for a single proportion. The traditional (Wald/Asymptotic) CI can estimate the upper and lower bounds above 1 and below 0, respectively. In these cases, researchers usually truncate the value to the appropriate bound. My question is, if I want to calculate interval width, do I calculate it before or after truncation? By interval width, I am referring to the upper bound - lower bound.

Comment: The answer likely depends on how you intend to interpret "interval width:" what do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber I should have clarified that. By interval width, I am referring to (upper bound - lower bound).

Comment: I think you should also motivate why you want to compare the widths. It seems odd to report an interval that includes values outside the parameter space.

Comment: I want to use it to compare how "conservative" the intervals are. I've seen interval width used in other papers that compare CIs. The Wald instance is the only interval that I am looking at that can fall outside 0 and 1 so I'm not entirely sure how to handle it. I could throw out the "invalid" intervals but I think that is not realistic.

Comment: In one paper, I read, "Complementary to average coverage is average width... It is desirable to achieve the required coverage with the least width. Meaningful evaluation of average width presupposes truncation of any overshoot." I'm guessing that means truncate first?

Comment: Do it both ways, then, and compare your results.  One of the methods will give the same coverage and same power as the other but will yield a smaller average width, allowing you to ignore the other method.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Initially, would argue that, using classical theory, you should truncate since the CI (or confidence set) should be a subset of the parameter space (or family set).

However, an example caught me thinking, and I do not know if that is the best approach. Imagine that the true proportion is $\mathbf{p} = 0.95$, and you have two methods two construct CI's. The first method produces a CI of $(0.88,0.96)$, while the second returns $(0.94,1.04)$. Both CI's contain $\mathbf{p}$, the first one is shorter than the second without truncation, but is larger if you truncate.

If the parameter is near the boundary and you have a method "biased towards" the boundary and other one which is not, the comparation may not be a "fair" one if you truncate. @whuber suggestion seems the most appropriate.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, Lucas! Thank you for sharing your ideas.